# Mongo DB sharding concept of read/write

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to set up mongodb sharding and almost done.

```
 1. completed 1 config replicaSet
 2. completed 1 shardsvr replicaSet
 3. multiple mongos routers connected to config and shardsvr also done
```

I think I am almost completed about sharding and I can manage "SHARDED CLUSTER" in mongodb compass.

But I still unclear with the facts of read and write via mongos. Many sharding guide end at the point after mongos is running. But I want to know is my following structure is valid or not to run.

```
 1. I have 6 servers (3 normal,3 high performance web servers)
 2. Normal 3 servers run as config 
 3. High Performance 3 run as 1 shard and multiple mongos (mongos on each)
```

May I know is my structure in correct form or in wrong for sharding concept. Is it ready to use with application to connect mongos with this situation ? Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Your general description sounds reasonable assuming you have followed the standard tutorial to [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/). However, the true test of your configuration being ready to use would be inserting some data via the `mongos`.  Also, if you want to try sharding you need to have at least two shards ;-). Rather than asking if your config is ready to use, I would give it a test run and ask for help if you encounter a specific error message or outcome that you need help interpreting.